# iOS web speech recognition.onresult issue

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, webspeech-api, 8thwall-xr

I am trying to code an 8th Wall web app which uses speech recognition. I am having a lot of inconsistencies in iOS from one iPhone model to another one, where in some of them the speech result seems to be taking up to 1 minute and in others it is instant. I am aware of the complications in iOS with enabling audio, and have already handled the user action to enable the mic.

I am guessing that, for those iPhone models which take so long to load the speech recognition, are getting stuck in not identifying the .onresult function, but I am not entirely sure what the issue is since it's so inconsistent from one iPhone to the other one. Any idea what the problem might be or how I can work around the .onresult function?

```
`recognition.onstart = function () {
    speechBtn.textContent = 'Listening...'
    console.log('Listening... Speak into the microphone.');
    model.setAttribute('animation-mixer', 'clip: visualization; loop: repeat;');
  };


  // Handles the 'result' event of the speech recognition
  recognition.onresult = function (event) {

    const transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;

    console.log(transcript);
    model.removeAttribute('animation-mixer');
    SendMessage(transcript)

    const speechBtn = document.getElementById('btn')

      speechBtn.style.background='#FFFFFF';
      speechBtn.style.color='#007AFF';
      speechBtn.textContent = ' ! '


  };`
```

Thank you!

Any help would be appreciate it, since I have tried getting the speech in several ways for iOS and still haven't managed to get it to work in most iOS devices.